# How can we create an XML file using Javascript and save it in local machine and devices?

Tags: javascript, browser, download

How can we create an XML file using Javascript and save it in the local machine/Device from the browser? Is it possible to save it in the Mobile devices(Android/iPhone etc.)? I don't want to use it as a native application for mobile devices and need to work as a common web application for both desktop and mobile devices. I have tried the following code, but it is not working in FireFox and working fine in Chrome.

```
function download(filename, text) {
var elem = document.createElement('a');
elem.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
elem.setAttribute('download', filename);
elem.click();}    

download('test.txt', 'Hello world!');
```

I have also gone through Downloadify, and it is working for desktop browsers as it need flash 10+ (https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify) and not working for mobile devices especially for iPhone.

And also tried FileSaver, but it is also not working in devices (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

Is there any common library which can be used to create and save XML files in common desktop browsers and mobile devices(Android, iPhone etc.)

Please get me some possible solutions which can be used for both desktop browsers and Mobile Devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For storage you can use session storage / local storage feature avaialble in html 5, although it has ceertain size limitation.

Comment: @VineetKasat: No, I don't want to use local storage. It should download the file in XML format and the user would be able to upload the file in cloud storage(Dropbox, Google drive, Skydrive etc)